# How to connect fan coil (condo) wiring with Google Nest

Tags: thermostat, nest

My old thermostat wiring looks like this:
[image]

So its good I have a C wire and its running on 24v.  The hard thing is the fan control.  It's a proprietary 3 speed fan - where do I wire those 4 wires to?  What is Fan "Com"?

I plan to purchase a Google Nest Thermostat but the compatibility tool is not complete as I have MORE wires than they need for fan control.

Answer (score 1):

From the Google Nest Support Page at:

[Nest Support Page](https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/9259652?hl=en)

[image: Nest Multi-speed and a Fan]

It's not clear what the tech will do but I suspect they have some additional hardware that controls the fan.

Comment: Great, have to pay another $300 for a 15 minute job